# How to copy a cookie in Windows 8.1 Metro IE from one domain to another

Tags: windows-8.1, internet-explorer, modern-ui, cookies

I want to copy all cookies from domain1.com to domain2.com for the Windows 8.1 Metro IE browser. How can I do that? Where are the files stored?

Comment: How is a cookie from one website going to be valid for an entirely different website both sites have to have an open session for this to work

Comment: I currently have fiddler redirecting domain1.com to domain2.com just so the browser sends the cookies it stored from domain1.com, but I'd prefer to just copy, it would be easier as redirecting globally causes me some problems. In this scenario domain1.com is Prod and domain2.com is my local machine, running the same code, and for dev purposes I need to use the same cookies, but I can't authenticate on my local machine and create the cookies there